# racket postfix to prefix

Tags: racket, postfix-mta, prefix

I have a series of expressions to convert from postfix to prefix and I thought that I would try to write a program to do it for me in DrRacket. I am getting stuck with some of the more complex ones such as `(10 (1 2 3 +) ^)`.

I have the very simple case down for `(1 2 \*)` → `(\* 1 2)`. I have set these expressions up as a list and I know that you have to use cdr/car and recursion to do it but that is where I get stuck.

My inputs will be something along the lines of `'(1 2 +)`.

I have for simple things such as `'(1 2 +)`:

```
(define ans '())
(define (post-pre lst)
  (set! ans (list (last lst) (first lst) (second lst))))
```

For the more complex stuff I have this (which fails to work correctly):

```
(define ans '())
(define (post-pre-comp lst)
  (cond [(pair? (car lst)) (post-pre-comp (car lst))]
        [(pair? (cdr lst)) (post-pre-comp (cdr lst))]
        [else (set! ans (list (last lst) (first lst) (second lst)))]))
```

Obviously I am getting tripped up because `(cdr lst)` will return a pair most of the time. I'm guessing my structure of the else statement is wrong and I need it to be `cons` instead of `list`, but I'm not sure how to get that to work properly in this case.

Comment: Does the expressions arrive as lists where for `(1 2 *)` the list elements are: "(", "1", "2", "*", ")" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```scm
(define (postfix->prefix expr)
  (cond
    [(and (list? expr) (not (null? expr)))
     (define op (last expr))
     (define args (drop-right expr 1))
     (cons op (map postfix->prefix args))]
    [else expr]))
```

This operates on the structure recursively by using `map` to call itself on the arguments to each call.

Answer (score 1):

Were you thinking of something like this?

```scm
(define (pp sxp)
  (cond
    ((null? sxp) sxp)
    ((list? sxp) (let-values (((args op) (split-at-right sxp 1)))
                   (cons (car op) (map pp args))))
    (else sxp)))
```

then

```scm
> (pp '(1 2 *))
'(* 1 2)
> (pp '(10 (1 2 3 +) ^))
'(^ 10 (+ 1 2 3))
```